# guardar variable sin que se "limpie" al hacer return view C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, entity-framework, aspx

tengo un pequeño problema, resulta que estoy realizando en mi proyecto dos filtros (Uno por fecha y el otro por empresa). El filtro por fecha funciona perfecto hago el cambio por fecha y filtra bien pero esa fecha que le mando quiero que quede guardada en una variable, al momento de hacer el return view esa fecha mandada no la guarda, "Limpia el modelo" y yo necesito que esa fecha la deje fija en algun lado de mi controlador (Que no se limpie).

ScreenShot
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Antes del return view la fecha today1 tiene esos datos como datetime.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Despues del return view (Con el código aun en ejecución) La variable today1 queda vacía.

Codigo C#

```
public class CierreController : Controller
{

    MVELEntitiess cm = new MVELEntitiess();
    private string fecha = null;
    private DateTime today1 = DateTime.Today;// fecha actual, inicializada global, puesto que todos los metodos la usan, y posteriormente se le asigna una fecha que contenga datos
    private DateTime inicio;// fecha inicio/fin. inicializada global puesto que todos los metodos la utilizan para filtrar la cantidad de dias del mes que contiene datos
    private DateTime fin;
    private int[] graficodays;// en los ActionResult se llenara con la cantidad de dias del mes que contiene datos, pasados a un formato que recibe la libreria del grafico
    private decimal?[] valorgraficodiario; // en los ActionResult se llenara con el valor margen operativo para cada dia del mes convertidos a un formato para el grafico
    private NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo("es-AR", false).NumberFormat; // le otorga el formato chileno a los valores y valores monetarios
    private NumberFormatInfo us = new CultureInfo("es-AR", false).NumberFormat; // Otorga el formato en - US
    public DateTime fechafiltroempresa;



    public ActionResult Cierre(FormCollection ddl1, string zonas, string empresas)// metodo ActionResult que llena toda la vista para ser mostrada por el navegador
    {

        fecha = ddl1["TextBox1"];
        if (fecha != null)
        {

            today1 = Convert.ToDateTime(fecha.ToString().Substring(3, 2) + "-" + fecha.ToString().Substring(0, 2) + "-" + fecha.ToString().Substring(6, 4));
            fechafiltroempresa = today1;
            // return RedirectToAction("NewMethod", "Cierre", new{today1});
        }

        double iny, ret, bal, ingr;

        string[] seriesgrafico = new string[1];

        seriesgrafico[0] = "Datos";
        cm.zona = "";
        cm.empresa = "";



        if (zonas == "norte")
        {
            // el filtro puede cambiarse, al modificar el "value" que retorna desde el html
            ViewBag.zona = " - Zona Norte ";

        }

        else if (zonas == "centro")
        {
            cm.zona = " - Zona Centro ";

        }
        else if (zonas == "sur")
        {
            cm.zona = " - Zona Sur ";

        }
        if (empresas == "Enel Generación")
        {
            cm.empresa = " - ENEL ";
        }

        return NewMethod(zonas, empresas, out iny, out ret, out bal, out ingr, seriesgrafico);
    }

    private ActionResult NewMethod(string zonas, string empresas, out double iny, out double ret, out double bal, out double ingr, string[] seriesgrafico)
    {
        cm.minimotecnico = minimoTecnico(today1, zonas, empresas);// minimo tecnico siempre debe ser el primer metodo en ser llamado, puesto que tambien obtiene la fecha a presentar en la vista
        cm.costomarginal = costoMarginal(today1, zonas, empresas);
        cm.ingresoscompania = ingresoCompania(today1, zonas, empresas);
        cm.costooperacional = costoOperacion(today1, zonas, empresas);
        ingr = ingresoTarifario(today1, zonas, empresas);
        cm.ingresotarifario = ingr.ToString("C", nfi);
        cm.margenoperativo = margenOperativo(today1, zonas, empresas);
        iny = inyecciones(today1, zonas, empresas);
        cm.inyecciones = iny.ToString("N", nfi);// el argumento "N" indica que es una cifra numerica y "nfi" es la variable que indica el pais de formato
        ret = retiros(today1, zonas, empresas);
        cm.retiros = ret.ToString("N", nfi);
        cm.inyeccionesVAL = inyeccionesValorizadas(today1, zonas, empresas);
        cm.retirosVAL = retirosValorizados(today1, zonas, empresas);
        cm.balance = balance(iny, ret);

        bal = balanceValorizados(today1, zonas, empresas);
        cm.balanceVAL = bal.ToString("C", us);


        cm.balanceReal = balanceReal(bal, ingr);

        cm.fechainicio = inicio.ToString("dd MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-CL"));
        cm.fechafin = fin.ToString("dd MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-CL"));
        cm.fechagrafico = today1.ToString("MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-CL"));
        cm.cantidaddias = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(graficodays);// depende de funcion margenOperativo
        cm.valordiario = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(valorgraficodiario);
        cm.fechapdf = today1;


        int[] valorestudio = new int[valorgraficodiario.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < valorgraficodiario.Length; i++)
        {
            valorestudio[i] = 0;

        }
        cm.valorestudio = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(valorestudio);
        ViewBag.estudio = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(seriesgrafico);
        ViewBag.titulo = "Cierre" + cm.zona + "" + cm.empresa + "";
        ViewBag.titulopdf = "";// titulo que se mostrara en el pdf, esta vacio por que no debe mostrarse en el navegador solo en el pdf, puesto que se llenara en actionresult posterior


        return View("~/Views/Cierre/Cierre.aspx", cm);
    }
```

es MVC-2 (Con aspx)

Alguna idea? acá el extracto de mi código aspx.

```html
<div id="myModalFecha" class="modal fade" role="dialog">

            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" style="; left: 50%; top: 50%; margin-left: -140px; margin-top: -240px;">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Fecha</h4>


                        <div class="modal-body">

                            <form id="filtrosFormFecha" method="post" class="form-horizontal">

                                <div class="well row">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div>
                                            <h3 style="text-align: center; font-family: Univers Light; font-size: 18px; color: #073492;">Fecha:</h3>
                                            <%using (Html.BeginForm("Cierre", "Cierre"))
                                                {%>
                                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                                                <asp:textbox id="TextBox1" name="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
                                                <div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-12" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                                                </div>
                                                <%-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">--%>
                                                <%--<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">--%>
                                                <%--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>--%>
                                                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
                                                <script>
                                                    $( function() {
                                                        $("[id*=TextBox1]").datepicker({dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy'});
            
                                                        // $("[id*=TextBox1]").datepicker({dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy'});
                                                    } );
                                                </script>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <center>
            <div class="form-group">
```

Lo que necesito basicamente es que esa variable today1 no se limpie o alguna manera de guardarla.

Comment: puedes revisar el siguiente link http://tiracodigo.com/index.php/programacion/mvc/formas-de-almacenar-datos-temporales-en-asp-net-mvc-viewdata-viewbag-tempdata-y-session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres mantener el valor de la variable una vez haya terminado el request, tienes que guardarlo en sesión, o en una cookie. Las variables declaradas en tu controlador se inicializan y se eliminan con cada request.

Guardarlo en sesión y recuperarlo de sesión sería lo más fácil. Puedes poner este código en cualquier método dentro de tu controlador:

```
//Guardar el valor:
Session["today1"] = DateTime.Now;
//Recuperar el valor
var fechaEnSesion = Session["today1"];
```